# Is it possible to compare two data-attribute using css

Tags: html, css

i have a list of `span`  each span have two data-attribute `data-search` and `data-get-search`, so simply what i am trying to do is to display only the spans that have `data-search` equals to `data-get-search`, something like this :

**check out the snippet:**

```css
   .child:not([data-search *=data-get-search]) {
        display: none;
      
            }
```

```html
<div id="main" class="container">
  <div class="child" data-search="first" data-get-search="first"><span>first</span></div> 
  <div class="child" data-search="second" data-get-search="first"><span>second</span></div>
  <div class="child" data-search="third" data-get-search="first"><span>third</span></div>
  <div class="child" data-search="fourth" data-get-search="first"><span>fourth</span></div>
  <div class="child" data-search="fifth" data-get-search="first"><span data-search="fifth">fifth</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: css is a styling language, it is not meant for complicated queries where you are testing attributes against each other, you will either have to test this server side and output a class or client side and change the style with js

Comment: With css you have to write rules for all combination like this `div[data-search="first"][data-get-search="first"]` and so on. Or using a little js script.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Pete suggested in the comments, you should use javascript for this.

Something like:

---

**Code Snippet:**

```js
(function() {

  var child = document.querySelectorAll(".child");

  for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
    var dataSearch = child[i].getAttribute("data-search"),
      dataGetSearch = child[i].getAttribute("data-get-search");

    if (dataSearch === dataGetSearch) {
      child[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<div id="main" class="container">
  <div class="child" data-search="first" data-get-search="first"><span>first</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child" data-search="second" data-get-search="first"><span>second</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child" data-search="third" data-get-search="first"><span>third</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child" data-search="fourth" data-get-search="first"><span>fourth</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child" data-search="fifth" data-get-search="first"><span data-search="fifth">fifth</span>
  </div>
</div>
```